# Lock one of WP Network sites for not registered users

Tags: multisite, multisite-user-management

I have a blog network (Multisite), with domain mapping plugin installed, and some of my sites are under development, so I want to lock them from not registered users.

I tested a few plugins designed for this purpose (*Private Only*, *Private WP suite*, *Private WP*, *Members Only*, *Registered Users Only*, *Absolute Privacy* and *Wp-Private*) and all failed.

I accessed site, saw login form, filled it in, marked "Remember Me", logged in and I was redirected to Dashboard (user section) not to site itself. When I re-entered site URL (domain) I again saw login page, though I marked "Remember Me". There is not way I can access site itself.

I even wrote my own, as simple as possible, plugin for this:

```
function show_guest_notice()
{
    if(!is_user_logged_in())
    {
        echo('No way, man!');
        die();
    }
}

add_action('get_header', 'show_guest_notice');
```

and it also failed.

It seems that either `is_user_logged_in()` or string user cookie fails on Multisite with Domain Mapping plugin.

I saw [this post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/is_user_logged_in-not-working-as-expected?replies=17) and answer by *amontobin* ("*(...) was a domain mapping cookie issue. Now working fine*"), but it only assured me that using Multisite with Domain Mapping is source of these problems, but it brings no solution to it.

So, can anyone help me or got any idea how to make site bloking (`is_user_logged_in()`) work on Multisite network with Domain Mapping plugin enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t have the domain mapping on a test installation at hand currently, but what *should work* is:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'auth_redirect' );
```

As a plugin here: [T5 Force Log In](https://gist.github.com/3521964).
[`auth_redirect()`](http://queryposts.com/function/auth_redirect/) is WordPress’ native handler for authentication, if it doesn’t work, something is broken in core code.

Comment: This also doesen't work. The only difference is, that after login, I'm not redirected to Dashboard, but back to login page (but without any error, which means -- as I assume -- that login was successful, only login cookie was not stored correctly). From the [support forum thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/is_user_logged_in-not-working-as-expected?replies=17) I assume, that the problem is not in core code, but rather _Domain Mapping_ plugin is interferencing somehow.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that login cookie is set for incorrect domain. If you have _Domain Mapping_ plugin enabled, it will always redirect browser to declared domain. So, for example, I have `one.page.com` site, mapped to `one.com` domain. Whenever I enter `one.page.com` URL, I'm redirected to `one.com` domain, if  _Domain Mapping_ plugin is enabled. Wordpress problably writes down login cookie for `one.page.com`, which is not available for `one.com` and everything fails. Dashboard is always accessible under `one.page.com` (plugin is enabled only for frontend), so this works fine.

Comment: Issue [reported](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/frontend-login-fails-with-domain-mapping-enabled?replies=1) in _Domain Mapping_ plugin support forum.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the plugin [Authenticator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/authenticator/), it works with Multisite too.
If you publish different parts of content via oauth or a kex, the use the [development version](https://github.com/bueltge/Authenticator).

Comment: Have you read my comments above, to toscho's answer? The problem is not in Multisite, but with Domain Mapping plugin enabled. I'm pretty sure, even without testing, that even Authenticator will fail in this situation. Simply because Wordpress itself fails, as it records login cookie for a different domain then is actually used (after redirection done by Domain Mapping).

Comment: Yes, I Have read this; but I use the plugin in a MU with Domain-Mapping.

Comment: Problem has been solved. All I needed to do, was to switch main domain of each site from default subdomain address to top-level domain that is mapped to that site, through Domain Mapping. I think that now all force-login plugins should work, but I decided to use `underConstruction` plugin, as it best fit my needs. Thanks.