# security issue in wordpress?

Tags: buddypress, security, hacks

I have installed wordpress in `www.mysite.com/user` and now suppose if someone is familiare with wordpress he/she can easily access my stuffs through `www.mysite.com/user/members`
`www.mysite.com/user/groups` etc even he can see all stuffs from `www.mysite.com/user` without logging in to my site.Is there any way to prevent this.something like access denied if he is not logged in or any kind of redirection to a specific url.
or something like You don’t have permission to access `/members/` on this server .I am facing lots of problem because of this.I am using frisco for buddypress theme.

Answer (score 2):

You can [force all visitors to log in](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72088/73) before they are allowed to see the pages. This will not work for attachments.

But … if that already is a problem for your site – why did you install WordPress in a publicly accessible directory? You should plan visibility first, then run the installation.

Consider [HTTP Basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) if you think your users can handle that.

Comment: I tried to install Private BuddyPress.which works fine but the only problem with this plugin is it does not allow to user register.when user clicks on registration it redirects to login page.is there any way not to include registration from this redirection.

Comment: Yes, see the code in my linked answer. It does not include the registration page.

Comment: authenticator plugin is not working nor T5 Force Log In.facing the same issue again.Is there any way to get rid of this problem.can i modify http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/private-buddypress/ to allow registration.?

Comment: @user1916876 This plugin offers an option to exclude registration pages.

Comment: ya but i am unable to do it.

Comment: in plugin Faq they told to exclude registration from Settings -> Privacy but there is no option of privacy.Is there any way to modify it manually thanxx